# Parse CSV file in an object

Tags: powershell, parsing

We have some pretty large log files (3-8Gb) that are delimited with spaces, with 64 headers. I need to search these and pull out the search term, but only need the data from 5 of the 64 headers.

I came across [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hkzd8spCfCU) by Tobias Weltner. After viewing it, I have some snippets of code but seem to be stuck in actually getting any results.

Essentially I need to search on 5 headers from a much larger file. The code that i have so far is :

```
$Search = "J89HD"
$logfile = "C:\Logs\CP8945KGT.log"

ForEach-Object {

    $line = $_
    $infos = $line -split " "

    $hashtable = [Ordered]@{}
        $hashtable.date = $infos[0] 
        $hashtable.time = $infos[1]
        $hashtable.Index = $infos[2]
        $hashtable.source = $infos[3]
        $hashtable.destination = $infos[-1]

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $hashtable

    Get-Content -Path $hashtable |
        Where-Object { $_ -match "$Search" } |
        Select-Object -Last 20 |
        Out-GridView
}
```

The error message that I get is:

```
Get-Content: Cannot find path 'C:\System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary' because it does not exist.
At C:\scripts\testing01.ps1:17 char:1
+ Get-Content -Path  $hashtable | Where-Object {$_ -match "$Search"} |  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\System.Colle...deredDictionary:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Comment: You don't supply an object to `ForEach-Object` it could iterate over. Does the log file have a header? Show a sample of the log in your edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet based on what you want to do and pieces of your code. This is untested as we don't have sample input data to test with.

```
$Search = "J89HD"
$logfile = "C:\Logs\CP8945KGT.log"

#load file
Get-Content -Path $logfile |

    #apply search filter on each line
    Where-Object { $_ -match $Search } |

    #keep only last 20 lines
    Select-Object -Last 20 |

    #for each line
    ForEach-Object {

        #store the line in a variable
        $line = $_

        #split the line on spaces to get an array
        $infos = $line -split " "

        #build a hashtable with properties holding specific cells of the array
        $hashtable = [Ordered]@{
            date = $infos[0] 
            time = $infos[1]
            Index = $infos[2]
            source = $infos[3]
            destination = $infos[-1]
        }

        #build a custom object with the properties in the hastable
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $hashtable

    #display the objects in a window
    } | Out-GridView
```

I'll try to explain what is wrong with your syntax:

1. the `ForEach-Object` block is meant to be processed for each element in the pipeline, so you have to put it *in* the pipeline
2. the closing `}` of the `hashtable` declaration should be after the properties
3. `Get-Content -Path` expects a file path and you're giving it a `hashtable` (the error you get is due to this)
4. `Get-Content` should not be in the `ForEach-Object` block since you don't want to load the file more than once; it's the beginning of your pipeline.

Comment: Many thanks for the edited script, but it throws an error message.

A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.
At C:\scripts\Log-Parser2.ps1:24 char:13
+             $hashtable.date = $infos[0]
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Collecti...deredDictionary:OrderedDictionary) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidNullKey

Comment: I have been able to get a cut down version of the sample data also. 

Though the real log file is pretty large, and has more data, this is the key info that i would like to extract when querying it. 

"C:\Logs\CP8945KGT.log"
2017.05.19 19:16 C J2-Send-CL6TT01012017 KL878EJDH-- 88PL34-GOOLE01021223 KL878EJDH-- 6HDJW
2017.05.19 19:16 A J2-Send-CL6TT01022017 KL878EJDH-- 88PL34-GOOLE01022017 KL878EJDH-- KDKJF
2017.05.19 19:16 B J2-Send-CL6TT01032017 KL878EJDH-- 88PL34-GOOLE01032017 KL878EJDH-- DJWJS
2017.05.19 19:16 A J2-Send-CL6TT01042017 KL878EJDH-- 88PL34-GOOLE01042017 KL878EJDH-- 8327E

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44084840/edit) to add this

Comment: It works as expected, many thanks for thehelp.

What was the silly mistake that you made..

Is there any good links for determining what the code should be for other delimeters, such as tab, or comma, or semi colon.